# Django: Querying an abstract base class

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I've got a situation where I'm modelling a football match, and each match has a set of events related to it, that relate to what happened during the game. So something a bit like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    time = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Goal(Event):
    scorer = models.ForeignKey('Player')

class PitchInvasion(Event):
    number_of_people = models.IntegerField()

class FootballMatch(models.Model):
    events = models.ForeignKey('Event')
```

Forgive the far fetched example, but it's there to show that these subclasses of `Event` could be anything. What I then want to do is to be able to query all those events and order them on time, to give a chronological view of what happened in that match.

However, with `abstract = True`, the `Event` objects end up with a `pitchinvasion_set`, `goal_set` and so on, . Would this be solved by setting `abstract = False` and using concrete inheritance? I've read that doing this is [a bad idea, as it introduces an extra join](http://jacobian.org/writing/concrete-inheritance/).

What's the best way to deal with situations like this?

Comment: Django Model class inheritance (real or abstract) is *not* true inheritance in the Python sense. It is more of a convenience option than anything else. I had to deal with something similar about a year ago and never really found a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Peter Rowell's comment - model inheritance isn't what you think it is, and in my opinion is very rarely useful.

A much better way to approach this is with [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). So you'd have a `Match` model, with an `events = GenericRelation()`, and each of the Event types has a `GenericForeignKey` back to Match. Then you could do `match.events.all()` and get all the separate events for that match.

If you like, you can still use abstract inheritance for the base class for the events, if they do all share some fields such as description and time.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this sounds like exactly what I'm after. Do you know if it's possible to administer all generic relations for an object in a single list within the admin? I'm guessing it's not possible.