# Django model inheritance and hasattr() on fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm struggling with this one. Let's say my models are in the following `testapp` app `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models

class Parent(models.Model):
    my_attribute = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Child(Parent):
    child_stuff = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

Now, if I try this (in console for example)

(InteractiveConsole)

> from testapp.models import Child
>
> hasattr(Child, 'my_attribute')

False

> c = Child()
>
> hasattr(c, 'my_attribute')

True

This feels really weird to me (because `Parent` IS ABSTRACT). How could I check the fields of `Child`? I was expecting the first hasattr to return True. Should I try via `_meta` to get the field by name and check if it's returning a field or not? It seems tricky for a simple need...

Cheers !

Comment: Maybe you mean to do `hasattr(Child(), 'my_attribute')`?  The callable itself is different than an instance of it.

Comment: Yes but I would have wanted to check that attribute without a class instance. Is that not weird the class itself does not have the field with the Parent being abstract?

Comment: I don't know enough about it, but apparently [Django model class inheritance is not the same as general Python inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809043/django-querying-an-abstract-base-class#comment8086174_6809043). Maybe it's more about what tables get created, so you can't rely on your assumption. `_meta` is indeed the preferred way to get that information, particularly after Django 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django 1.8 has a documented [`_meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#module-django.db.models.options) api.

You can either use [`get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields),

```
my_attribute in [field.name for field in Child._meta.get_fields()]
```

Note that `get_fields` has an `include_parents` option which you can use include or exclude fields from parent models.

Or you could use [`get_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field), and catch the `FieldDoesNotExist` exception.

```
from django.db.models import FieldDoesNotExist

try:
    field = Child._meta.get_field('my_attribute')
except FieldDoesNotExist:
    # field does not exist
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print "my_attribute" in  [
    field.name for field in 
    Child._meta.get_fields(include_parents=True, include_hidden=True)
]
```

Comment: Well, I agree but is there any better way to achieve this? Like a has_field method? The hasattr() behavior is quite puzzling

Comment: It doesn't look like. Now I'm not sure what you want to achieve but you might not even need to check if the field exists; instead you can just catch the `AttributeError` exception.

Comment: I think it should be `._meta.get_fields()` , at least according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api).